# Assign button Click event through TemplateBinding on Avalonia

Tags: c#, xaml, avaloniaui

I have a TemplatedControl `SoftwareReleaseControl`, which displays some texts and a button. I need this button to inherit its `Click` event from the property `OnInstallClick` that is specified when creating the `SoftwareReleaseControl` control.

The problem is: I can't make it work. It does not bind to the template's property. I've tried copying source code from Avalonia's [button (ClickEvent)](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/src/Avalonia.Controls/Button.cs) to the control's Code-Behind. It shows as an EventHandler, but is not passed to the button, and also gives an `Unable to find suitable setter or adder [...]` error.

SoftwareReleaseControl.xaml:

```xml
<Styles xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="using:Updater.Controls">
    <Design.PreviewWith>
        <StackPanel Spacing="5">
            <Panel Classes="Spacing"/>
            <my:SoftwareReleaseControl Title="..." Version="..." Description="..." Installed="..."/>
            <my:SoftwareReleaseControl Title="..." Version="..." Description="..." Installed="..."/>
        </StackPanel>

    </Design.PreviewWith>

    <Style Selector="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource text}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Lato"/>
    </Style>
    [...]
    <Style Selector="my|SoftwareReleaseControl">
        [...]
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Panel Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                           HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                           VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                           Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                           MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}">
                        <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                              RowDefinitions="46, *, 40">
                            [...]

                            <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
            ======= HERE ===>>  <Button x:Name="PART_footer_installButton"
                                        Content="Instalar"
            ======= PROBLEM ===>>       Click="{TemplateBinding OnInstallClick}">
                                    <Button.Styles>
                                        <Style Selector="Button#PART_footer_installButton">
                                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
                                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource text}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{TemplateBinding Tag}"/>
                                        </Style>
                                        <Style Selector="Button#PART_footer_installButton:pointerover /template/ ContentPresenter#PART_ContentPresenter">
                                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource text}"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Button.Styles>
                                </Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </Panel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Styles>
```

SoftwareReleaseControl.xaml.cs (code-behind):

```cs
using Avalonia;
using Avalonia.Controls;
using Avalonia.Controls.Primitives;
using Avalonia.Interactivity;
using System;

namespace Updater.Controls
{
    public partial class SoftwareReleaseControl : TemplatedControl
    {
        public SoftwareReleaseControl()
        {
            
        }
        public static readonly RoutedEvent<RoutedEventArgs> OnInstallClickEvent = RoutedEvent.Register<Button, RoutedEventArgs>(nameof(OnInstallClick), RoutingStrategies.Bubble);
        public event EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs> OnInstallClick
        {
            add => AddHandler(OnInstallClickEvent, value);
            remove => RemoveHandler(OnInstallClickEvent, value);
        }
        [...]
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml (where I'm trying to show the controls):

```xml
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="using:Updater.ViewModels"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:my="using:Updater.Controls"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Width="800" Height="520"
        x:Class="Updater.Views.MainWindow"
        Icon="/Assets/avalonia-logo.ico"
        Title="Updater">

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          Background="{DynamicResource window.background}"
          RowDefinitions="40, *" ColumnDefinitions="*">
        [...]
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
            <StackPanel Spacing="5" x:Name="stk_releases">
                <Panel Classes="Spacing"/>
==== HERE ===>> <my:SoftwareReleaseControl Title="..." Version="..." Description="..." Installed="..." OnInstallClick="{Binding btn_OnClick}"/>
                <my:SoftwareReleaseControl Title="..." Version="..." Description="..." Installed="..." OnInstallClick="{Binding btn_OnClick}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

It doesn't really matter if I will need to implement `btn_OnClick` in the MainWindow's code-behind or in the ViewModel.

The current code is giving me the errors:

- `Unable to find suitable setter or adder for property OnInstallClick of type Updater:Updater.Controls.SoftwareReleaseControl for argument Avalonia.Markup:Avalonia.Data.Binding, available setter parameter lists are: System.EventHandler[[Avalonia.Interactivity.RoutedEventArgs, Avalonia.Interactivity]]` on *MainWindow.xaml*, on the `OnInstallClick="{Binding btn_OnClick}"`.
- `Unable to find suitable setter or adder for property Click of type Avalonia.Controls:Avalonia.Controls.Button for argument Avalonia.Base:Avalonia.Data.IBinding, available setter parameter lists are: System.EventHandler`1<Avalonia.Interactivity.RoutedEventArgs> `on *SoftwareReleaseControl.xaml*`, on the `Click="{TemplateBinding OnInstallClick}"`.

Yes, I did specify the *StyleInclude* on App.xaml.

**Why *Click* and not *Command*:** I need the *sender* object so I can get the Tag property of the button. There will be many of this control on the window and I need to sort out which one got clicked.

tl;dr: How can I specify an event handler on my templated control, in a way that the button inside it can inherit the handler as its *Click* (not Command). Where will I need to implement the handler? ViewModel or CodeBehind?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on using *Click*, and instead found a way to send the button itself to a Command.

SoftwareReleaseControl.xaml:

```xml
[...]
<Button x:Name="PART_footer_installButton"
    Command="{Binding _OnInstallClick}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Button.Styles>
        <Style Selector="Button#PART_footer_installButton">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource text}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{TemplateBinding Tag}"/>
        </Style>
        <Style Selector="Button#PART_footer_installButton:pointerover /template/ ContentPresenter#PART_ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource text}"/>
        </Style>
    </Button.Styles>
</Button>
[...]
```

SoftwareReleaseControl.xaml.cs:

```cs
namespace Updater.Controls
{
    public partial class SoftwareReleaseControl : TemplatedControl
    {
        public SoftwareReleaseControl()
        {
            DataContext = this;
        }
        public event EventHandler InstallClick;
        private void _OnInstallClick(object? sender)
        {
            EventHandler handler = InstallClick;
            handler?.Invoke(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        [...]
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```cs
namespace Updater.Views
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel(this);

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                var t = new SoftwareReleaseControl();
                t.Description = (string)App.Current.Resources["lorem.50"];
                t.Installed = i % 2 == 0;
                t.Tag = i;
                t.InstallClick += T_InstallClick;
                stk_releases.Children.Add(t);
            }
        }

        private void T_InstallClick(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("123");
            if (sender is Button btn)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(btn.Tag);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in Avalonia.

What you must do is, override OnApplyTemplate of your control. In this method access the methods argument name scope and find your control.

```
Var btn = e.NameScope.Find<Button>("PART_footer_installButton");
Btn.Click += (s, e) => {};
```