# How to add event to control inside TemplatedControl

Tags: c#, events, avalonia

I have a TemplatedControl and some daughter controls inside it. I want to assign them some events. Initially axaml file cannot access C# module, but when I add `x:Class="MyNamespace.MyTemplatedControl"` to axaml, although C# code is seen from it, an error occurs:

> MyTemplatedControl.axaml(9, 6): [XAMLIL] No Content property or any Add methods found for type MyDesktopApp:MyNamespace.MyTemplatedControl Line 9, position 6.

Looking for solution, all I have found was  [this variant with Button and its Command property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73978779/assign-button-click-event-through-templatebinding-on-avalonia). But in this case I will be restricted only with click event, without opportunity to handle text changed, drag and drop, getting and loosing input focus and other popular actions.

MyTemplatedControl.axaml:

```
<Styles xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:controls="using:MyNamespace"
        x:Class="MyNamespace.MyTemplatedControl">
    <Design.PreviewWith>
        <controls:MyTemplatedControl />
    </Design.PreviewWith>

    <Style Selector="controls|MyTemplatedControl">
        <!-- Set Defaults -->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <ControlTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock
                        Text="Templated Control"
                        DoubleTapped="InputElement_OnTapped"/>
                    <TextBox
                        KeyDown="InputElement_OnKeyDown"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Styles>
```

MyTmplatedControl.axaml.cs:

```
using Avalonia.Controls;
using Avalonia.Controls.Primitives;
using Avalonia.Input;
using Avalonia.Interactivity;
using Avalonia.Media;

namespace MyNamespace;

public class MyTemplatedControl : TemplatedControl
{
    private void InputElement_OnTapped(object? sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as TextBlock).Text = "DOUBLE TAPPED";
    }

    private void InputElement_OnKeyDown(object? sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as TextBox).Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    }
}
```

PS. As a beginner, I also don't know yet, how to access controls from .axaml.cs to .axaml, help me, if it is possible, but I think, this is a topic for another issue.